# Int template in an array/vector/whatever

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I need to know how to create an array/vector containing a class defined somewhat like:

```
template<unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns> 
class Matrix
{
     ......
};
```

Where `rows` and `columns` may vary from item to item in the vector. 
Since the templates change, the vector regards them as different types and so it doesn't work.

Btw, I chose this format since many operations with matrices require the number of rows and columns to be the same and the templates make checking for it much easier.

Comment: Please reread your question, from the beginning. When you realize the major problem with your question, and why nobody will have any idea what you're talking about, please fix it.

Comment: `a` and `b`????

Comment: @Eichhörnchen he is giving out sample object name for his classes , i think

Comment: You talk about vertex and matrixes. You want a vector of matrices? Then create a Matrix class , then import `<vector>`, and finally `std::vector<Matrix> a;`

Comment: Oh crap, thanks. Fixed now. I had rewritten this several times hoping to make it clearer and hadn't noticed that wording error left over from my original drafts

Answer (score 1):

you might can try something like this

```
class MatrixBase
{
public:
    virtual ~MatrixBase() {}

    virtual int getrow() = 0;
    virtual int getcol() = 0;
};

template<unsigned int row, unsigned int column>
class Matrix : public MatrixBase
{
public:

    virtual int getrow() 
    {
        return row;
    }

    virtual int getcol()
    {
        return column;
    }
};

Matrix<4, 4> m1;
Matrix<3, 3> m2;
Matrix<2, 2> m3;

vector<MatrixBase*> v;
v.push_back(&m1);
v.push_back(&m2);
v.push_back(&m3);
```

is thats not an option than you might wanna think of a design change.

Comment: ok, but as much as OP told us, he doesn't need templates at all

Comment: I do, I just really screwed up when I was writing my question. My wording was terrible and vague - I think it's fixed now